# centos 7 execute remote script from local

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

I'm working on a script to sync a folder from Windows to a Linux server with Rsync and I manage to get it work with git bash and the rsync executable.

In Centso I added the `syncinguser` to the `sudoer -> syncinguser  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` to allow the execution of Rsync, how can I allow the same user to run a `.sh` file to complete the sync process or a php command?

I want to sync a Laravel application so I need to run the command `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache` after the sync has finished.

I would also like to change `owner:group` like `chown -R user:psacln *` but I'm quite happy with the fact that doesn't change the rights on the folders E.g: 0777 permission on the public folder.

This is my script in windows so far:

```
rsync -rt --chown=user:group (being ignored I think because user's permissions) 
--exclude ".env" --exclude "storage" --exclude "public/storage" --progress 
--rsync-path="sudo rsync" -e "ssh -p <port>" 
'/c/path/to/local/folder/' syncinguser@<ip address>:/remote/path/
```

how can I add something like this after the sync:

```
ssh yncinguser@<ip address> php artisan cache:clear
ssh syncinguser@<ip address> php artisan config:cache
// OR
ssh syncinguser@<ip address>:/remote/path/to/completesync.sh
```

where `completesync.sh` will run the 2 php artisan command and apply recursively the owner:group of all files/folders as when they come from windows they are all root:root

I cannot connect as a root because we blocked it, you need to connect as a normal user and then switch to root.

```
 ssh -p <ssh port> syncinguser@<IP ADDRESSED> '/path/to/script.sh'
```

permissions denied, same if I connect as a normal user

Comment: You need to write a shell script. What's the question exactly? What you've shown isn't really a script, but a single command. A script is a text file with a series of commands, with eventual flow control (conditions checks, etc).

Comment: the final script will be `rsync / php artisan cache:clear / php artisan config:cache` and in the one that will runs between the 2 linux server also `php artisan down / php artisan down` before and after to run the sync and cleaning the cache, it's not a really complex script, just an automation of some commands. that command is saved in a .sh file in windows that i run calling it through the git bash

Comment: OK, but I don't get what you're asking or what the problem is :)

Comment: I've updated the question, maybe it's a bit clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you need two scripts: one on the source machine, and another one on the destination machine. The script on the source machine should be something like:

```
rsync ... ... ... syncuser@destination:/dest/path
ssh syncuser@destination "sudo /some/path/to/completesync.sh"
```

And on the destination machine, the script `/some/path/to/completesync.sh` which contains something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

# whatever else you need to run as root
```

Be careful to have restricted rights on this script:

```
chown root:root /path/to/completesync.sh && chmod 700 /path/to/completesync.sh
```

Last, modify `/etc/sudoers` on the destination machine so that "syncuser" can run both rsync and your script as root:

```
syncuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync, /path/to/completesync.sh
```

Now running the script on the source machine should complete the whole process in one operation.

Comment: I change the permission to `777` and in visudo `syncuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` but nothing to do, I always have permission denied. I was trying to do a simple `chown -R ...` it runs if I use that user on the server and i run the script manual but not from remote

Comment: Uh, of course it misses the "sudo" command in the first script :)